# How to OAuth token refresh angularjs or javascript applications

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I am new at Oauth protocol and created an identity server application that creates `access_token` for applications.

But life time of a token is about 5 minutes. So I am getting an `access_token` on my angularjs javascript application and save it in cooke while user login. And some times later the token expires.

How can I refresh the token. For example send token request all 2 minutes. or another way.

And which grant type can I use?

Answer (score 0):

You can find here an example: https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth/blob/master/src/http-auth-interceptor.js
It uses a buffer to store the rejected $http calls and it broadcasts some events if the refresh token is expired.
You can find here another example: http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/